# iPhone simulator: Is it possible to restore a real iPhone backup to it?

Tags: backup, ios-simulator

as the question says, I have a backup of an actual iPhone. Now I want a "copy" of the content in my simulator. The reason is that my real iPhone contains third party application data that I want to have in my simulator too.

Is that possible?

Thanks,
Norbert

Comment: I don't think that is possible. But I'll be happy to be proved otherwise. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitely not possible, because apps have to be compiled specifically to run on the simulator and iPhone, and such builds are not compatible with each other as they are built to run on different processors.

Edit to add: you can copy data/content (and you can, for Apple-supplied apps like the Address Book that are provided by Apple for the simulator) but unless you have a version of the app compiled for the simulator that can run, the content is obviously no use.

Comment: as the chips now run the same code recompilation is not necessary so that no longer provides the rationale for why it doesn’t work.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to trick the Simulator by putting files there:

```
~/Library/Application Support/iOS Simulator
```

You can also put the files you need in your application project or have a look at Apple Documentation about Application Data[1](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/120-Building_and_Running_Applications/building_and_running_applications.html)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the short answer: no.